# To what level of detail must you know the contents of a demiplane to connect to it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

The Demiplane spell states (emphasis mine):

> Each time you cast this spell, you can create a new demiplane, or have the shadowy door connect to a demiplane you created with a previous casting of this spell. **Additionally, if you know the Nature and contents of a demiplane created by a casting of this spell by another creature, you can have the shadowy door connect to its demiplane instead.**

How exact must your knowledge of the contents of a demiplane be before you can use this clause in the spell to connect to it?

Some examples of scenarios where you may or may not know enough detail:

- You know the demiplane solely contains a particular creature, but you don't know everything that's in that creature's pockets.
- You know the demiplane solely contains a giant pile of gold coins, and roughly how large it is, but don't know exactly how many coins there are.
- The demiplane contains 20 distinct items, and you know 19 of them.

Comment: related: [What is the "nature" of a demiplane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71955)

Answer (score 15):

## To the extent your DM deems sufficient

There is no general rule for this, nor does the spell specify, so it's up to the DM.

Let's face it, the existence and nature of any demiplane you might want to go to is the domain of the DM anyway, so it'll be on them to decide how much familiarity is needed to get there. You'll have enough familiarity if you were meant to go there by spell and/or that doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

Does the character have prior knowledge of this demiplane, either from having been there with the original caster, or having read a journal that details this demiplane? If not, I would not let the character connect to it. These aren't normal Planes of existence that anybody could have knowledge of, these are privates demiplanes made by powerful casters, so a character's knowledge of said plane would be limited by their experiences in game.

Answer (score -3):

You gotta know the content an stuff pretty much exact 30x30 room stuck there forever, you could throw more stuff in there later.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. All answers should directly answer the question; this seems intended as a comment on another answer, [which you'll be able to do once you have more reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).